# how to upgrade ubuntu 14.04LTS to 16LTS from command line　without GUI?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, upgrade

I can't log into my desktop so I have to upgrade my system from 14.04LTS to 16LTS. I have done:

```
      sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
      sudo reboot
      sudo update-manager -d
```

but I get errors:

```
    GTK warning: cannot open display
```

it seems to me that it needs a GUI prompt for me to accept and then continue, so my question is:how to upgrade ubuntu 14.04LTS to 16LTS from　command line　without GUI?

---

I tried `sudo do-release-upgrade`
but I get errors as below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUxHz.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLn6K.jpg

Answer (score 8):

The recommended way to upgrade a Server Edition installation is to use the do-release-upgrade utility. Part of the update-manager-core package, it does not have any graphical dependencies and is installed by default.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html

This will work for your installation as well (i.e. not just for Server Editions).

Comment: I tried sudo do-release-upgrade but I get errors as below: http://i.imgur.com/nBihtEj.jpg http://i.imgur.com/44k0IOn.jpg

Comment: First remove all ppa's from /etc/apt/sources.list. Now run sudo do-release-upgrade. Reboot and add new ppa's for the current OS version.

Answer (score -1):

Run this, you should be notified that there's a new release available, follow the prompts to do the upgrade.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answer