# How can I upgrade live ec2 intsance runninng ubuntu 14.04 LTS to latest stable ec2 ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, 18.04, upgrade, lts, amazon-ec2

Looking for a clear way of upgrading one of live ec2 machine running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. As stack is quite older now, I know we can upgrade to older version to a new version but how about from older LTS to another LTS version in my case.

I'll appreciate your expertise on this.

Thank you folks for redirecting to another links, for sure all that putting more confusion to my basic question.

Comment: You have to use the [do-release-upgrade](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/do-release-upgrade.8.html) command .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906265/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-14-04lts-to-16lts-from-command-line-without-gui)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: @ParsaMousavi can I really go for do-release-upgrade on live machine, as suggested. Will it not make any tearing issues and will it update to the 18.04 LTS

Comment: That is not how you use an instance. Create a new instance for 18.04 and connect your data disk to the new instance.

Comment: HI @Rinzwind, creating a new instance with 18.04 for each and every 14.04 machine doesn't sound practical.

Comment: Yes it is. It is also a perfect method ensuring you can go back to the older instance.  Plus ZERO downtime: you keep the old OS running while you set up the new one. The 1st time it takes a bit of setting this up (since you need to change location for apache and mysql if you use those). After that it is the quickest way to upgrade your systems. I have been doing that since 12.04 and somewhere next week I will be upgrading 40+ instances to 20.04. Instances are set up to do it like that.

Comment: Instances come with a warning: when the instance can not boot it is DEAD. So you do NOT change the boot process when it is working (an upgrade does change the boot process). Conclusion: you create boot disks and personal disks. A personal disk can always be added to a new boot disk. And you should consider boot disk burnable: learn to create then from the console so when a boot disk dies you have a spare boot disks ready.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)